# Is it possible to render a view in XML or JSON using ruby

Tags: xml, ruby-on-rails-3, json, view, hobo

Rendering a JSON or XML view in rails 3 is straight forward enough.  As Hobo does not use views, I cannot work out how to do the same in a hobo project and the docs are not very illuminating.  Has anyone done this?

I am using rails 3.0.3 and hobo 1.3.0 pre29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right solution is:

```
def show
    hobo_show do |expects|
      expects.json { render :json => @user.to_json }
      expects.html { hobo_show }
    end
end
```

for index:

```
def index
    hobo_index do |expects|
      expects.json { render :json => @users.to_json }
      expects.html { hobo_index }
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done it in a Rails3/Hobo1.3 project yet, but I've certainly rendered non-DRYML views in Hobo projects.   It should work exactly the same as in Rails.

However, for JSON or XML I usually just do it in the controller:

```
def show
 respond_to do |expects|
   expects.json { render :json => {...} }
   expects.html { hobo_show }
 end
end
```

Comment: P.S.   The Hobo-users mailing list is the best place to get Hobo questions answered.